# iOS - UITextView doesn't draw text?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview, uitextview

I have a UITextView on the screen.
This UITextView is covered by a UIView.

When I set the text for this UITextView, if the textView is not visible (UIView is covering it), it doesn't draw the text.

So when I remove the view that is covering my textView there is no text in my textView. If I try scrolling the textview the text will appear suddenly.

any way to force the UITextView to draw the text at all times? (This only happens when I have too much text in it (about 1000 characters))

I tried calling `[textView setNeedsDisplay]`, before and after setting 'text' and it didn't fix the problem

Comment: You could try calling -setNeedsDisplay on the UITextView after you've set the text.

Comment: Why do you have the UIView covering it?

Comment: @Karoly S it's like a drawer that expands and shrinks on top of my main view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most things in the system will not display when hidden, which would be a waste of resources.

The correct approach is to call setNeedsDisplay: on the UITextView AFTER it has been un-hidden, then it should draw immediatley.

Comment: Is there a method in UIView that gets called when the view appears on the screen? If there is I can override, and call setNeedsDisplay after calling the super

Comment: In theory setNeedsDisplay *is* the method that should be called when a view appears on screen or is un-obscured.

Comment: calling setNeedsDisplay doesn't work for me, just saying you might want to check somewhere else [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7679354/offscreen-uitextview-invisible-clear-text-in-ios-5)

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem, my UITextView does not draw text until I try scrolling it or its parent. [textView setNeedsDisplay] does not work for me. Finally, I increase textView 1px and the problem's gone.

```
CGRect frame = textView.frame;
frame.size.height += 1;
textView.frame = frame;
```

I know this method is ugly but it does work.

Answer (score 0):

The limit to the number of characters in a `UITextView` seems to be around relatively low ([see the post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617618/uitextview-not-showing-text-until-i-rotate-it)).

The poster in the link I posted suggests putting your content into a [`UIWebView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html), which can handle a large amount of text.

Comment: That's not my case, because as I mentioned after scrolling the TextVuew, the text appears suddenly

Comment: The poster also says that he can see the text after he rotates the screen. After a certain length is past, it becomes unstable. I'd suggest using less text or a `UIWebView` so you don't have to deal with a buggy interface.

Comment: Unfortunately less text is not my choice, the data comes from the server and I have to display it

Comment: Check out [this tutorial](http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/windows-views/display-rich-text-using-a-uiwebview) for an easy tutorial for how to load text into a `UIWebView`.

Comment: Thanks, I know how to use a UIWebView, but I rather find a solution and use a UITextView

Answer (score 0):

Same problem.  We have a textview that is configured and put into the view while hidden or offscreen.  Most likely due to Apple optimizing `UITextView` so that it doesn't do layout and drawing unless it is onscreen and visible.

Calling `setNeedsDisplay` doesn't work because of the optimizations.  `setNeedsDisplay` gets called quite often, so imagine a `UITextView` doing layout and drawing quite often?  Thus the solution above is ugly but works:  add a pixel to the frame which will trigger the `UITextView` to re-layout and redraw.  We went with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Since UITextView is a subclass of UIScrollView, I did something like this:

```
CGPoint offset = self.textView.contentOffset;
offset.y++;
[self.textView setContentOffset:offset];
offset.y--;
[self.textView setContentOffset:offset];
```

the same as @Tùng Đỗ without changing the frame... still looks ugly.