# Offscreen UITextView invisible/clear text in iOS 5

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uikit, ios5

I've got an off-screen UITextView instance loaded from a nib which is moved into the screen frame when the user taps a "comment" button. Any text the enter uses is invisible. If the user rotates the device, the text appears.

I've tried throwing setNeedsDisplay and setNeedsLayout, as well as setting the text, textColor, and font properties *after* it comes on screen with no luck.

I have an [example Xcode project](http://ashfurrow.com/bug.zip) demonstrating the bug.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm getting something very similar to this on iOS6. . except the UITextView is loaded from code. . .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't solve this problem so I wait until the view has finished animating on screen and recreate the UITextView, remove the old one, and replace it with the new one.

It's very inelegant since I even need to keep a BOOL ivar for remembering if I've already replaced the text view (or not).

Answer (score 1):

so the solution is to instantiate the UITextView in your code and add it as a subview when the textview needs to appear in the screen for the first time.
Then you can make it disappear and reappear and it should be OK.

```
UITextView *aTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 89, 684, 441)];
[aTextView setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0]];
[addCommentView insertSubview:aTextView atIndex:1];
[self setCommentTextView:aTextView];
[aTextView release];
```

It's working great for me !

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same bug in a beta version of the iOS5-SDK and had to build a workaround. However, the bug seems to be fixed in the GM-version of iOS5.

Answer (score -3):

Bug is still present in official iOS5 SDK. Any issues?

*SOLVED*

The problem was a logic error without any link with iOS5. No issue at all, after i've corrected it.

Comment: can u tell us about your case, please?